# Firebase: User Authenticated but database query is not initiated

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

This is a weird problem for me.

Basically, I am building an app which upon login and authenticating user, it will bring up a page to load the data from Firebase Database and save to realm.

All is working fine until I tried to authenticate user without login (To check if they are already logged in so as to automatically bring up the home page view controller).

This is my auth code

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth

class AuthUser {

  func userCheck(completion:(message:String)->()){

    var message = ""

    let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser

    if (user != nil) {

        print("User is already logged in")

        message = "LoggedIn"

    } else {

        print("User is not logged in")
        message = "notLoggedIn"

    }

    completion(message: message)

  }
}
```

and this is my import data code

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import RealmSwift

class MenuDataRealm {

  func importData(completion: (message:String)->()){

    print("Initiating Menu Data Import...")

    // Realm
    let realm = try! Realm()

    print("Importing...")

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    ref.child("Category").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

        print("Start Menu Data Retrieval")
....
```

The problem is that upon logging, the log stop printing after "Importing..." and stop there. If I logged in normally (instead of authenticating user automatically), it will run through the entire function perfectly and does not stop at "Importing..."

this is the log of normal login

```
2016-08-25 01:25:05.481 MannaCatering[33636:480265] Configuring the default app.
2016-08-25 01:25:05.502 MannaCatering[33636:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3200000 started
2016-08-25 01:25:05.503 MannaCatering[33636:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: - FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled 
2016-08-25 01:25:05.507: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> FIRInstanceID AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification handlers. To disable add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
2016-08-25 01:25:05.515 MannaCatering[33636:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
2016-08-25 01:25:05.569 MannaCatering[33636:480305] Version 1.0.2 of     Realm is now available: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/v1.0.2/CHANGELOG.md
User is already logged in
2016-08-25 01:25:05.817 MannaCatering[33636:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO>    Firebase Analytics enabled
Logging In... with Email:caieylau@gmail.com and Password:********
User is now Logged In
Redirecting to Loading Data...
Initiating Menu Data Import...
Importing...
Start Menu Data Retrieval
Completed Menu Data Import
Accessing Firebase
Retrieving Details
User Details Retrieved
Redirecting to Gallery
```

This is the log of when I try to authenticate the user automatically upon loading

```
2016-08-25 01:34:53.080 MannaCatering[33972:485449] Configuring the default app.
2016-08-25 01:34:53.108 MannaCatering[33972:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3200000 started
2016-08-25 01:34:53.109 MannaCatering[33972:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled 
2016-08-25 01:34:53.111: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> FIRInstanceID AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification handlers. To disable add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
2016-08-25 01:34:53.159 MannaCatering[33972:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
2016-08-25 01:34:53.166 MannaCatering[33972:485629] Version 1.0.2 of Realm is now available: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/v1.0.2/CHANGELOG.md
User is already logged in
Redirecting to Loading Data...
Initiating Menu Data Import...
Importing...
2016-08-25 01:34:53.613 MannaCatering[33972:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled
```

There is also another thing worth mentioning which is that it does work sometimes and run through the entire function working as it was intended when I authenticate automatically.

However, this always only happen right after I remove the AuthUser.userCheck function, restart the app, log in via the manual entry method, and add the function back in.

It seems to be that the auth function, despite showing that the user is logged in, is not always true and hence the database query did not work.

However, I tested that out by changing the database read and write rules to true, allowing access without authentication but it was still stuck at "Importing..." despite doing so.

I hope this is not too confusing and do let me know if you need any additional information to understand my problem.

Comment: Give your JSON tree..Try using breaking points to find at which line was it breaking

Answer (score 0):

Try importing Firebase as it is at the top. I believe that you no longer need to import FireAuth and all that. Firebase should hold all of that as it is.

```
import Firebase
```

^That's all I need to do in order to authenticate, talk to the database, ect.

I don't fully understand your question, but if your having trouble initializing your user and observing his information with a query..
This is what I do in order to pull information and update a text label of the current user.:

```
var user: FIRUser!
func authenticateUser() {
    self.user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().users.child(user!.uid).child("userInfo").observeEventType(.Value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

        self.fullNameValue = snapshot.value!["fullName"] as! String

        }
}
```

I hope I could help.

Comment: Hi. it didn't work for me. It is really a weird problem that I cant even explain it properly. Basically, after the user is authenticated, (printed: User is already logged in), sometimes it is behaving as though the user is not logged in, so it just stops there, right before it fetches the user details. However, on other times, it works perfectly, mostly right after I perform a manual log in. (Removing the automatic login, and adding it back again). I managed to pull off a workaround by routing it to login after authentication & it works fine nw. Thanks for your answer tho. Appreciate it.